# If commenter's email match based on array then print author role

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, comments, user-roles

I want to print author role based on array defined value if commenter's email matched.

Here is config array defined.

```
// Get Comment

$comment = get_comment();
// Get Commenters email
$match_email = $comment->comment_author_email;


// Config arrays


$config = [
    'verified_email' => [
        'sakshikr652@gmail.com' => [
            'role' => 'Seo Expert',
        ],
        'sabhitra628@gmail.com' => [
            'role' => 'Manager',
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is foreach loop.

```
foreach ($config as $group => $users) {
    foreach ($users as $author => $email) {

        if (($email === $match_email) && have_comments()) {
            echo $email['role'];
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

How to print author role from config arrays value if email id matched.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: match with key $author not with the value which will have array `[
            'role' => 'Seo Expert',
        ]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current scenario I could see that `$email` inside if should be replaced with `$author`:

```
if ($author === $match_email && have_comments()) {
            echo $email['role'];
            break;
}
```